# How to use different build targets when running capacitor sync command in an angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am currently using Capacitor in my Angular project. So far, I had defined several build targets (`development`, `staging` and `production`) in my `angular.json` file and using the `ng build --configuration=<target_name>` to make deployments with different configuration.

I would like to achieve the same functionality in Capacitor so I can make different builds based on the target. I updated my environment file(s) as follows:

```js
export const environment = {
  target: 'development',
  // ...
}
```

And also updated the `capacitor.config.ts` file:

```js
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';
import {environment} from "./src/environments/environment";

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  webDir: `dist/${environment.target}`,
  // ...
}
```

However, this always results in `webDir` being `dist/development` because I could not find a way to specify my build target when updating my capacitor project. Therefore, the environment file being used is always `environment.ts`, instead of being replaced by `environment.production.ts` (assuming I wanted to build for production).

At the moment I use the following steps to build for my desired target:

1. To make a build for my desired target:

```
npx ng build --configuration=<build_target>
```

2. Manually change the `capacitor.config.ts` file:

```js
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  webDir: 'dist/<build_target>',
  // ...
}
```

3. Then update Capacitor project:

```
npx cap sync ios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environments file replacement is an angular thing and only replaces the file in the code inside the src folder.

Capacitor is framework agnostic and knows nothing about that replacement and angular is not replacing the file for source code outside the src folder (like `capacitor.config.ts`).

So you'll have to use a different approach that doesn't involves the angular replacement, in example you can do something like this:

```
import { environment as devEnvironment } from './src/environments/environment';
import { environment as prodEnvironment } from './src/environments/environment.prod';

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodEnvironment : devEnvironment;
```

and run the sync command like this `NODE_ENV=production npx cap sync android`